# Are modern CPUs or SOCs stateless?

Tags: firmware

According to this older post: https://security.stackexchange.com/a/174968/271114
Intel processors are stateless.

Nowadays a "CPU" is often a SOC integrating neural engines, GPUs, coprocessors, secure enclaves and more.

Other architectures like ARM64, RISC-V and POWER9 are also more common. Do they (or maybe others) keep state? Could malware hide in a modern SOC?

Comment: most CPU's also come with some sort of memory or cache... so there's definitely "state" or "states"... not to mention RAM.  Maybe clarify the question a bit?  Firmware could contain malware... RAM can contain malware for a certain period of time (or be vulnerable to stack overflow)... caches?  Probably them too?

Comment: I am not an expert for CPU internals but considering the branch prediction function block which is crucial for fast CPUs I would assume that for enhancing the prediction probability it should consider some sort of state. This start may not be usable for malware but at least it is a state.